# How to get all links inside block in DomReadyphp?

Tags: php, domready

I tried to get all links in block `div` with class:

```
$details = $xpath->query('//div[@class="meta"]');

foreach ($details as $node)
{
    $arr = $node->getElementsByTagName("a");
    var_dump($arr); die();

    foreach($arr as $item) {
       // Empty $item
     }
}
```

Comment: And? What happened?

Comment: That was funny lol.